# Location Services not working in iOS 6

Tags: cllocationmanager, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS 6 and Location Services not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522004/ios-6-and-location-services-not-working)

Our app's location services have stopped functioning in iOS 6. They work fine in iOS 5.  When I call CLLocationManager's startUpdatingLocation method it never prompts the user for access and our app doesn't show up in the Settings Location Services page.

Anyone seen this before? I really have no idea where to look.  I have tried stripping down our app to just a single view controller and it still doesn't work. Maybe something in the build settings?

Edit:
I created a new target and it works in there.

Comment: I asked my question first so good job closing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the problem was we did not have CFBundleDisplayName declared in the .plist file.  We had CFBundleName but not CFBundleDisplayName.

Comment: I have this already, still not working with me. It works fine on previous iOS versions.

Answer (score -1):

I created the project with XCode 4.4, after install Xcode 4.5 location doesn't work. Declaring in the .plist file key CFBundleDisplayName location now is working.

Comment: Location services and localization are completely different topics.

Comment: yes... location, sorry!!