# MKMapView crash on showUserLocation on iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, mapkit

I just recently updated my iOS SDK to the latest release (6.0).
I used to have a couple of map views in my app, *MKMapView*, that were
used to show the user location.

After the update, upon setting the property

```
mapView.showUserLoaction = YES;
```

The app crashes with the following exception:

> -[MKCoreLocationProvider locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x155af5f0

This happened on iPhone iOS 6.0 Simulator, not on device/simulators with previous versions of the OS. 
The error can be reproduced just by setting the property. Otherwise the app run smooth.

The bug came up just after updating the SDK. Moreover, I didn't test on a iOS 6 device yet (all the test on such a device have been performed with the previous version of the SDK though, and the app didn't crash).

What could be the issue?

**UPDATE**: in iOS6 Device there are no issues. The problem appears just on the iOS 6 Simulator

Comment: post the code you in have in -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

Comment: Are you using CLLocationManager in the code?? coz this method belongs to CLLocationManager

Comment: that's the thing: I'm not. In the controllers where the crash happens, I just setup a MKMapView. Then, if I also set the *showUserLocation* property to *YES*, boom

Comment: so, @Eric , there is no code to show in this case. Because I don't have that function implemented in the MKMapView delegate.

Comment: First check that you are already able to get current location for apple's map application..

Comment: the method `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` has been deprecated on iOS6, is really curious that is being called. Maybe you can find a solution in the answers of this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522004/ios-6-and-location-services-not-working)

Comment: Also, don't use the `xcode` tag for questions which are **not** related to Xcode.

Comment: check your IBOutlet connections

Comment: I don't use the Interface Builder. Plus:
@Rajneesh071 I'm able to get the current location from the maps app in the simulator

Comment: Just find in simulator setting > privacy > Location > and LocationService is on

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

if you are using a MKMapViewYou should also be using if you are doing something with the userlocation

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

}
```

Comment: yes I implemented that delegate. I didn't try to use *setShowsUserLocation* , but it would be complete nonsense imho if that would work. The *dot* notation and the *message notation* are equivalent in objective-c.

Answer (score -1):

I am using this delegate method and this is working fine for me in ios6

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
}
```

Comment: As I told, I'm not implementing the CLLocationManager delegate anywhere. So that code shouldn't be needed in my controller.

Comment: replace this method -[MKCoreLocationProvider locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:]: with my method

Comment: Where? I repeat: that method belongs to CLLocationManager delegate, and I'm not implementing it. You don't need to implement CLLocationManager delegate in order to use MKMapView.

Comment: Just find in simulator setting > privacy > Location > and LocationService is on.

Comment: As I said: "I'm able to get the current location from the maps app in the simulator", so that stuff is already fixed.

Comment: you did downVoted for my answer?